# Autoscrolling view pager causes frames to drop

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, frame-rate

I have an infinite and autoscrolling view pager with 3 pages (views, not fragments). Using `ObjectAnimator` I set up a dummy animation like so:

```
valueAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);
```

and in `onAnimationRepeat`, I use `setCurrentItem(nextItem, true)` to move to the next page. However if I sit and wait at this screen then UI performance gets lower and lower after 10 or so page changes (Using [TinyDancer](https://github.com/brianPlummer/TinyDancer) I have observed FPS dropping to 20 from 60).

However, changing the line to `setCurrentItem(nextItem, false)` (setting `smoothScroll` to false) the performance drop is eliminated.

Is there something about calling `setCurrentItem` multiple times that can cause this? Can I tweak the `smoothScroll` behaviour to fix this? Again, I have at most 5 views loaded in this pager at any time, and I have observed memory usage staying still when watching FPS drop.

Comment: Set the offscreen page limit of your viewPager to zero or one (setOffscreenPageLimit(0)).

Comment: I'm already setting it to 1; setting it to 0 gives the log message `Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely got to do with views that are being affected by the `ViewPager`. Is there a parent layout where the `ViewPager` resides? Check if you have a parent view. The dummy animation can be causing the parent layout to re-draw itself and the child elements many-a-times. This is especially troublesome when you have...wait for it...Nested views!